# How to measure the block production rate of the private chain

Tags: private-blockchain

I recently built an Ethereum private chain(clique) with two nodes. The genesis file is as follows:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 53783,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "arrowGlacierBlock": 0,
    "grayGlacierBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 0,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "difficulty": "1",
  "gasLimit": "80000000000000",
  "extradata": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111": { "balance": "500000000000000000000" },
    "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222": { "balance": "500000000000000000000" }
  }
}
```

The topology of the private chain is as follows:
[image]
I want to measure the block rate of this private chain. My idea is as follows: let Node1(server1) frequently initiate transactions to Node2(server2) for a certain period of time, I used the following code on server1 to achieve this behaviour:

```
i = 1
nonce = 0
while (i == 1) {
  eth.sendTransaction({
    from: eth.accounts[0],                                   //node1
    to: '0x2222222222222222222222222222222222222222',        //node2
    value: 10,
    nonce: nonce++
    })
  for (let j = 0; j < 30000; ++j) {
  }
}
```

Then I count the block generation rate per minute during this period, and then obtain the block generation rate of the private chain.

However, when I repeated the experiment, I found that the block rate fluctuated greatly for each experiment. Sometimes, the private chain generates blocks smoothly and records a smaller number of transactions per block. Sometimes, the block production speed of the private chain fluctuates greatly, and blocks that record a large number of transactions and are produced slowly appear frequently.

My questions are: 1) Why do the same experiments in the same experimental environment lead to different block generation situations. 2) Is there any way to more accurately measure the block production rate of the private chain I built?

**More details**:

experiment enviroment:

```
Geth
Version: 1.13.5-stable
Git Commit: 916d6a441a866cb618ae826c220866de118899f7
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.21.4
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=
```

Running private minners command:

```
geth --datadir node1 --port 30306 --bootnodes enode://410cccae8f204f84f5415d80dbf888ee76ddc59550846ccb9839e38ab285597c7fff7ddfd7200d0e7fb34e3018b87eee4d392c6ee0165f62adec40546fe3bd02@192.168.50.11:0?discport=30305 --networkid 53783 --unlock 0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 --password node1/password.txt --authrpc.port 8551 --mine --miner.etherbase 0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```